# Loop to send mail with Excel MailEnvelope: The operation failed because of network or other communication problems

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook for sending emails to users. It has a test mode so that emails are sent to my mailbox.

For each user I generate a specific message in a worksheet called 'canvas' then use the following code to send it:

```vb
Private Sub sendEmail(sendOnBehalfOf As String, email As String, emailCC As String, subject As String)
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
        .Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = sendOnBehalfOf
        .Item.To = email
        .Item.cc = emailCC
        .Item.subject = subject
        .Item.Send
    End With
End Sub
```

I get an error after about 30-40 emails:

> Run-time error '-2147417856 (80010100)':
>
> The operation failed because of network or other communication problems. Verify your connection and try again.

All emails are sent to my email as I am testing.

Some observations:

- The number of emails it sends before failing is generally the same
- The code starts fast then begins to slow down
- When I begin to receive emails in Outlook and when the macro fails seems to correlate
- I thought it may be the code running too fast for the MailEnvelope to keep up so I have added Sleep points in multiple places but the error still occurs

Comment: Do you have any pauses in the code elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I know when I automate heavy loops of internet explorer, if I don't add an ojbIE.Quit statement at the end of my sub function, the code will slow down so much so that the code will fail since it has 45 processes of IE open in the background. Maybe adding something along those lines would help keep the code running at swift pace.

If that doesn't do the trick, I would just change the `.Send` command to `.Display` and click the send button manually, or add a `SendKeys` command to 'send' the email that way and see if that doesn't stop the error from occurring. As long as you have the appropriate 'wait' commands in your code, the SendKeys function should work fine.

Comment: I am not sure about the quit/kill command here as I am not loading anything with MailEnvelope just making it visible, wait commands are making no difference to this dying.  Entire macro works fine with the call to this function commented out so I know its something in here.

Answer (score 0):

Put a DoEvents after the line .Item.Send

Answer (score 0):

I have in the past the same kind of error, through this code (email in loop) you are flooding your email client and then you get the error.
My solution to this problem was to add a pause after sending the email from 1 to 5 seconds using:

    `Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#` 
 
Or you can put a counter and pause after 10 or so emails.